# Copied blocks and CLANG leak warnings

Tags: ios5, memory-management, asynchronous, clang, objective-c-blocks

I have a method which takes a block:

```
- (void)methodWithBlock:(blockType)block
```

The method starts out by copying `block`, because it does asynchronous things before using it, and it would be discarded otherwise. It then calls the method within another block, and then releases it, within that block. Summarily:

```
- (void)methodWithBlock:(blockType)block
{
    block = [block copy];
    [something asyncStuffWithFinishedBlock:^{
        // ..
        block();
        [block release];
    }];
}
```

CLANG complains about memory leaks for "block". If I remove the copy and release statements the block will be gone by the time it's called -- at least earlier crashes indicates that this is the case.

Is this the wrong way to do things? If so, how should I do the above -- i.e. a block callback from within a block statement in a method? I can't store block as an instance variable, as the method could be called repeatedly with different arguments while the asynchronous part is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the `-copy` and `-release` should be unnecessary.  The `-asyncStuffWithFinishedBlock:` method must copy the block that's passed to it.  When a block is copied and it references other block objects, it copies those block objects, too.  You need to figure out the real nature of the crash you were seeing.

Second, you are releasing the wrong thing.  `[block copy]` does not modify the `block` (the receiver of the `-copy` message) somehow turning it into a copy.  It *returns* a copy of that block.  It is this returned copy that you want to reference both in the invocation statement (`block();`) and when releasing.

So, you could do:

```
block = [block copy];
[something asyncStuffWithFinishedBlock:^{
    // ..
    block();
    [block release];
}];
```

Note the reassignment of the local `block` variable to point to the copy.

Think of it this way: would you ever copy a string the way you attempted to copy that block?  Would you do:

```
[someString copy];
// ... use someString ...
[someString release];
```

Comment: Oops, I typo'd -- I did mean block = [block copy] in that statement.

Comment: As for them being unnecessary... gah. Okay, thanks I'll do some research.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should do the `release` inside the block like that. You are assuming that the block gets called exactly once. But just from the code, we don't know that. It could be that the method does not execute the block at all, in which case you won't be releasing, so leaking. It could also be the case that the method executes the block more than once, in which case you would be over-releasing.

If you really want to copy it, you need to release it outside the block like this (the scope that retains something should be responsible for releasing it):

```
- (void)methodWithBlock:(blockType)block
{
    block = [block copy];
    [something asyncStuffWithFinishedBlock:^{
        // ..
        block();
    }];
    [block release];
}
```

(It's irrelevant what `asyncStuffWithFinishedBlock` might to with its argument; according to the memory management rules, if it needs to keep it around for longer, it will need to retain or copy it (for blocks it needs to copy it).)

However, as Ken Thomas pointed out, it shouldn't be necessary for you to copy it in this method since you're not storing the block anywhere. `asyncStuffWithFinishedBlock` should copy its argument block if it needs to run it asynchronously; and any blocks captured by that block should be copied when it is copied.

Comment: I forgot to mention that but yeah, the block is a one-time thing which is reset.